# youtube xml feed for single playlist

Tags: php, xml, web-services, rss, youtube

Perhaps I am missing something but how does one go about retrieving the xml feed of videos from a single YouTube playlist. I have tried all the ways listed on google and so on but they keep returning an invalid playlist if error even though the id is exactly the one in the youtube url that works on youtube.
Thanks

Comment: Just do as outlined, only take care you don't make any mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get listing of user's public playlists at:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/playlists?alt=rss&v=2

And you can get xml data for an individual playlist by at:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/AA8A0579E8329C7A?alt=rss&v=2

replace `AA8A0579E8329C7A` with the playlist-id you want.